# flask restx enum model

Tags: flask, enums, swagger, flask-restplus

How to create an Enum api model in **flask restx** with one string field without other properties so that the following description is generated in swagger.yml?

```
definitions:
    Colors:
      type: string
      enum: [black, white, red, green, blue]
```

[image]
Maybe some hacks will help?
Because now it seems like you can create an api model with properties only

Answer (score 2):

Oh, so I find solution for my question)

Self-answered, lol

You can define api model via json schema description:
https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/marshalling.html#define-model-using-json-schema

```
colors_api_model = api.schema_model('Colors', {
    'enum':
        ['black', 'white', 'red', 'green', 'blue'],
    'type': 'string'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For new comers, flask restx now supports an enum property for String type

```
        theme_color = api.model( "theme_color", {
            "appTheme": fields.String(description="UI primary colour",enum=["theme-red", "theme-pink", "theme-orange", "theme-yellow"])
        })
```

[Example documentation here](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swagger.html#documenting-the-fields)