# Dropdown menu in Swagger with Flask (restx)

Tags: python, api, drop-down-menu, swagger, flask-restx

I am building my first API with the flask-restx lib. I use it to generate a Swagger documentation of my API with annotations. I currently have some fields for a post method but they all accept input as strings by default and you have to type their values in Swagger ‘Try it out’. How do I make them dropdown lists so that a user chooses an input parameter from it?

I currently use the following decorators for my namespace:

```
@ns.route('/')
@ns.param('param_1', 'param1')
@ns.param('param_2', 'param2')
@ns.param('param_3', 'param3')
class EndpointName(Resource):
```

And I parse them in a post method like this:

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()  # initialize
parser.add_argument('param_1', type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument('param_2', type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument('param_3', type=int, required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

They are currently presented in swagger as input fields. How would I go about making them dropdowns with specific values to choose from? Should I add something to decorators are set types in the parser differently?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flask restx enum model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64253395/113116)

Comment: Hi. It does not. I currently use @Namespace.param decorator and RequestParser(). Not sure how to use the answer from the link in this context...

Comment: I added code snippets to my question. Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: did not find a flask way, but swagger expects `allowable values` looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/26647373/2361131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `@ns.param('param_1', 'param1')`, you can use [`@ns.expect(parser)`](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swagger.html#the-api-expect-decorator) or [`@ns.expect(parser, validate=True)`](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swagger.html#the-api-expect-decorator) for enabling payload validation and give `choices` in `parser.add_argument`

```py
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('param_1', type=str, required=True, choices=("yes", "no"))
...



@ns.route('/')
@ns.expect(parser)
class EndpointName(Resource):
   args = parser.parse_args()
...
```

Comment: Gentle reminder, don't put location ='json' , else the drop down won't show.

With choices argument you will able to see the enums render as drop down.

Upvote this.